# How can i run a method in a thread and call a method when the thread exits

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, process

I have been searching for an answer to this but cannot find a simple example to help me understand. I am writing win form app in c# that wraps up a bunch of command line tools used for video encoding. I have a method called **encodefiles** i want to run this method in a thread so that the UI can still operate. Once the thread has finished I want it to call another method so i know it has finished. i can then encode the next file or finish. all depends if there are any more files to encode.

I was getting the action i wanted when i was only running a single command line tool as i was using the process object which you can attach a finished event to. I want to the same for a thread but have no idea how.

In short i want to be able to do the following with a thread instead of a process

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start(commandLineExe, commandlineSwitches);
myprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myprocess.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_exited);
```

Hope that makes sense

Am using c# .NET 3.5 with visual studio 2010

Comment: What is the application are you running in the Process.Start? I mean the commandLineExe is it another c# console application?

Comment: The process code was just an example to demonstrate what he want to achieve with a thread. Something like `thread.Exited += OnExit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well if you are using winforms and you want to run a task in background and notify when its completed use [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

and handle the DoWork(), WorkerComplete(), progressChanged() events to get your work done.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class?
It gives you the option to fire 'progress changed' events.

Answer (score 1):

Create one more thread.  In the thread procedure for it, do:

```
yourMonitoredThread.Join();
CallYourProcedure(); //  can be event
```

EDIT:

You can derive from `Thread` and implement your needed event and use it encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class MyThread
{
    Thread _thread;

    public MyThread()
    { 
        _thread = new Thread(WorkerMethod);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void WorkerMethod()
    {
        // do something useful
        // [...]

        //Exiting this method = exit thread => trigger event
        Exited(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler Exited = delegate{};
}
```